Does modifying all weights of an undirected graph via multiplication/addition change the MST?
Suppose we have an undirected weighted graph G where each weight is a rational number. If there is a new graph G1 that has all the same vertices and edges, except each weight is multiplied by 2, is the MST still a valid MST of G1? What if there was another graph G2 that has all the same vertices and edges, except each weight has 2 added to it. Is the is the MST of G still a valid MST of G2?

It would seem to be fairly easy to prove this algebraically. What have you tried?
